# Command line tool to convert Markdown Pipe-Tables to Double-Pipe-Header-Tables

Tags: command-line-interface, markdown, pandoc, confluence, multimarkdown

I write my Markdown tables usually in the Pipe-Table syntax (used by [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#tables), [multimarkdown](https://fletcher.github.io/MultiMarkdown-6/syntax/tables.html), [php extra](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/) and others). Here an example:

```
| fruit  | price |
|--------|------:|
| apple  |  2.05 |
| pear   |  1.37 |
| orange |  3.09 |
```

In a [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence) wiki I can use Markdown (with some crutches), but the tables have to be in a (to me) odd format similar to Markdown:

```
||fruit||price||
|apple|2.05|
|pear|1.37|
|orange|3.09|
```

Which command line tool can I use to convert the former into the latter?

---

PS: I cannot go to HTML  instead of the Double-Pipe-Header-Tables because the Confluence instance I am targeting has HTML Marco not enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with version 2.7.3, pandoc supports Jira wiki markup as input and output format. That format is *mostly* identical to Confluence markup, so it should work to convert to that with

```
pandoc --to=jira YOUR-FILE.md
```

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what I was after. The pandoc _jira_ writer translates tables as expected. Thanks!